# Url Form Action Without ViewContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes

Is it possible to get a URL from an action without knowing ViewContext (e.g., in a controller)?  Something like this:

```
LinkBuilder.BuildUrlFromExpression(ViewContext context, Expression<Action<T>> action)
```

...but using Controller.RouteData instead of ViewContext.  I seem to have metal block on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I do it in a unit test:

```
    private string RouteValueDictionaryToUrl(RouteValueDictionary rvd)
    {
        var context = MvcMockHelpers.FakeHttpContext("~/");
        // _routes is a RouteCollection
        var vpd = _routes.GetVirtualPath(
            new RequestContext(context, _
                routes.GetRouteData(context)), rvd);
        return vpd.VirtualPath;
    }
```

Per comments, I'll adapt to a controller:

```
string path = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(
    new RequestContext(HttpContext, 
        RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(HttpContext)),
    new RouteValueDictionary( 
        new { controller = "Foo",
              action = "Bar" })).VirtualPath;
```

Replace "Foo" and "Bar" with real names. This is off the top of my head, so I can't guarantee that it's the most efficient solution possible, but it should get you on the right track.

Comment: I do not need the URL for the current request, but for some other action.

Comment: I understand. The solution above still applies. There is *no* connection to the current request there.

Comment: I don't understand then.  Let's say I want to get the Url for FooController.Bar("foo", "bar"), which would be "/MyVirtualDir/Foo.mvc/Bar/foo/bar".  How could I use this to get that in a (different) controller method?

Comment: Craig, can you also update your answer above, using a strongly typed controller (ie. Microsoft.Web.MVC) instead of having to hardcode the controller name and action? is that possible?

Comment: All controllers are strongly typed. You can certainly reflect the controller and action name if you can take the performance hit, but don't forget about ActionNameAttribute. If I were doing this, I'd try to find a way to use the framework's internal controller and action name caches.

Answer (score 4):

Craig, Thanks for the correct answer.  It works great, and it also go me thinking.  So in my drive to eliminate those refactor-resistent "magic strings" I have developed a variation on your solution:

```
public static string GetUrlFor<T>(this HttpContextBase c, Expression<Func<T, object>> action)
    where T : Controller
{
    return RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(
        new RequestContext(c, RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(c)), 
        GetRouteValuesFor(action)).VirtualPath;
}

public static RouteValueDictionary GetRouteValuesFor<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> action) 
    where T : Controller
{
    var methodCallExpresion = ((MethodCallExpression) action.Body);
    var controllerTypeName = methodCallExpresion.Object.Type.Name;
    var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(new
    {
        controller = controllerTypeName.Remove(controllerTypeName.LastIndexOf("Controller")), 
        action = methodCallExpresion.Method.Name
    });
    var methodParameters = methodCallExpresion.Method.GetParameters();
    for (var i = 0; i < methodParameters.Length; i++)
    {
        var value = Expression.Lambda(methodCallExpresion.Arguments[i]).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
        var name = methodParameters[i].Name;
        routeValues.Add(name, value);
    }
    return routeValues;
}
```

I know what some will say...dreaded reflection!  In my particular application, I think the benefit of maintainability outweighs performance conerns.  I welcome any feedback on this idea and the code.

Comment: Okay, this is a problem for testing controllers (any approach that uses Routes and RequestContext).  I cannot figure how to correctly stub HttpContext (even after some fun with Reflector).  I will put behind an interface to make controller more easily testable.

Comment: I was able to figure out how to stub HttpContext to make this work in tests.  The missing price was:

SetupResult.For(request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath).Return("~/");