# getting route to controller action (url) programmatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a controller named "AccountController" and action called "ResetPassword". From the html markup I can do something like:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "ResetPassword", "AccountController") %>
```

and it will output the correct url. Is there a way to do this programmatically? I am trying to get the url as a string in another class but System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper doesn't have an ActionLink() static method and creating an instance of the class doesn't have it either.

Note: If I try to create instances of HtmlHelper or UrlHelper I then need references to the View Context or Request Context and I can't figure out how to get those from the controller (to pass in to my class method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Url Form Action Without ViewContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363234/url-form-action-without-viewcontext) .

Answer (score 10):

Use `Url.Action` instead.

Comment: When I try to create an instance of UrlHelper it asks for a "requestContext". How do I get the requestContext so I can create an UrlHelper instance?

Comment: If you are in a controller, use the HttpContext property of the controller.

Comment: I am in a class outside the controller and HttpContext.Current will not work. I get a syntax error, it's the wrong type.

Comment: Try passing in the ViewContext then. Sorry.

Comment: Since I am calling my method from the Controller there doesn't seem to be any ViewContext

Comment: Can't you call it in your controller and pass the result to the other class/function?